# HTML code `&#39;` is breaking url after the code

Tags: php, url, url-encoding

I have an URL **"www.yourdomain.com?caption=mycaption`&#39;`goes here&title=mytitle"** which is GET request. 
But when I print $_GET array it prints only: 
`Array
(
    [caption] => mycaption
)`

I want: **"mycaption`&#39;`goes here"** to be get fetched as it is from URL(using $_GET array) so that I can save it to database.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: URL escaping is different from HTML entities. You have to use the right one ...

Comment: I just have some raw data which has such `&#39;` codes, I'm just pasting it while putting caption in URL. What could be the way to use it. Should I suppose to replace all these HTML codes with the respective special characters?

Comment: The ampersand in the URL indicates another URL parameter. It's not possible to use that URL in that form and get the result you require. How is that URL generated?

Answer (score 1):

you should try encoding and decoding the variable you are passing because escaping is not directly allowed in url.

Try this

```
   $caption=urlencode("mycaption' goes here");
```

and then pass $caption to your url

Comment: Thats right, no doubt it will work using encoding. But what if I'm manually putting text in URL?